# How to create sql select by 3 level expression and statement

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlite, search

How to create sql select by 3 level expression and statement

Normally, my website based on SQLite database and the search result will be display by $sql =

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM amz WHERE Title LIKE \"$qq%\" OR Price LIKE \"$qq%\" GROUP BY Title";.
```

Above will be search and select query that contains any search keyword from database in column Title or Price.

However, I need to create 3 expression and statement from database as:

1. Default will be search and display result as `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM amz WHERE Title LIKE \"$qq%\" OR Price LIKE \"$qq%\" GROUP BY Title";`
2. If can't find any search result from Title and Price column. Then SQL will be check in Category column as `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM amz WHERE Category LIKE \"$qq%\" GROUP BY Title";`
3. Finally, if not match in each column. SQL result will be echo custom message.

I try to create with myself. But it seems the result echo 1.) option only.

Example:

I search “bedding comforter set”. And in column Title in database had products contain this keyword without (s).

Initially, an expression will be check if it match 1). A statement will do selecting products from column Title or Price.

However, in column Category. I declare specific category to each product such as “bedding comforter sets” to Category.

So, if search not match bedding comforter sets in Title or Price. The result will be display products that match search query of bedding comforter sets in column Category instead Title or Price.

Finally, if not search query not match any in each column will be echo custom message.

Additional:

This is a screebshot comparing between query 1 and query 2 result

[image]

This screenshot is query 1 result that search keyword without (s) and like or match in Title column or Price column from database.

[image]

This screenshot is query 2 result that search keyword with (s) which like or match in Category column. This strange because it turns as Not Found while I set it to display result.

[image]

And this is my coding that I not sure it correct or not?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a requirement to write one sql to accomplish this?

You have essentially written pseudo-code:

> 1. Default will be search and display result as $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM amz WHERE Title LIKE \"$qq%\" OR Price LIKE \"$qq%\"
>      GROUP BY Title";
> 2. If can't find any search result from Title and Price column. Then SQL will be check in Category column as $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
>      amz WHERE Category LIKE \"$qq%\" GROUP BY Title";
> 3. Finally, if not match in each column. SQL result will be echo custom message.

Now start expressing it in language the machine understands. A starting point:

execute and fetch result from query 1
   **if** result set is not empty, display result
   **else** execute and fetch result from query 2
     **if** result set is not empty, display result
     **else** display custom message

--EDIT --
Based on screenshot of code, you are not running the mentioned queries at all, but some other query modified by the `str_repl`. Which seems to morph it into an aggregate query (`COUNT(*)`), and aggregate queries always return at least one row. That could cause this problem.

Comment: Yes. I need to do as you explain. But as I try, the result echo just query 1. If query was added (s) in keyword that match with Category as query 2, the result will be echo empty. As I notice it will do 1 expression only.

Comment: Sorry, must see the php code to understand further.

Comment: I see a possibility in the picture. Answer has been edited. Good luck.

Comment: So, which is the correct code I should edit as you recommend? I try to find the solution on the internet but not successfully to edit and make it worked. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what the correct code is. Based on how you have described the problem and the code you have displayed, everything I can help you with is already in the answer.